# cherrypy when to know that the server has started

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am trying to write some unit tests for a small web service written with Cherrypy and I am wondering what's the best way to figure out that the server has started, so i don't get connection refused if I try to connect too early to the service ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it figured out:

`cherrypy.engine.start(); cherrypy.server.wait()`
it's the way to go.

Otherwise, I think you can get away with some tricks with
`cherrypy.server.bus.states`